# Fourier Series of $\sin(x)$ for interval $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ and $0$ for $-\pi \leq x < 0,$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We have given the following function:
\begin{equation}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
         0, &  -\pi \leq x < 0, \\
         \sin(x), &   0 \leq x \leq \pi
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
My task is to calculate the fourier series and show that it converges pointwise against $f$.
We start with calculatin $a_0$
\begin{equation}
    a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx =\frac{1}{\pi} (-\cos(x)\Bigr|^\pi_0) = \frac{2}{\pi}
\end{equation}
For $a_n$ we get:
\begin{equation}
    a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x) \sin(nx)dx = -\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{\pi (n^2-1)}
\end{equation}
And for $b_n$
\begin{equation}
    b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x) \cos(nx)dx = \frac{\cos(n\pi)+1}{\pi (1-n^2)}
\end{equation}
I used wolfram alpha to calculate the last two. With that my series would be:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{2\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\pi)+1}{\pi (1-n^2)} \cos(nx) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n\pi)}{\pi (n^2-1)} \sin(nx)
\end{equation}
This is now something that I cannot really work with. First, $n = \pm 1$ isn't possible, but it's in my series?
Additonally, I cannot create my original function with this, at least I do not know how. And showing that it's converges to f
seems hard/impossible with what I have.
If I calculate some values, I see:
\begin{equation}
    a_n = 0 \ \ 
    b_{2n} = -\frac{2}{(4n^2-1)\pi} \ \ \textrm{and 0 otherwise.}
\end{equation}
This does not look too bad at all if I plot this in wolfram alpha, yet I know that this is not completely correct and I don't know how to show that this
converges to $f$.

Edit:

I now found this series, which seems to be the one I am looking for according to wolfram alpha: $$\frac{\sin(x)}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(4n^2-1)\pi} \cdot \cos(2nx)$$

Still, I cannot show the convergence of it.

Comment: Hint: The calculation of $a_n$ isn't the same for $n = 1$. Also, for the real version of Fourier series, the coefficients are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ so $n = -1$ is not an option.

Comment: For $n = 1$ I have $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. I simply add this, right?